# How to use distinct, order by and OFFSET LIMIT in cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working on cosmosdb. How distinct work in cosmos db with multiple column?

How to use distinct, order by and OFFSET LIMIT in cosmos DB?

```
**Below query return 100 records....**
SELECT distinct c.Code,c.Name, c._ts FROM c 

**// return 67 records**
SELECT   c.Code,c.Name, c._ts FROM c 
Where c.Name = 'SomeName' 
ORDER BY c._ts desc
OFFSET 50 LIMIT 10

**// return 7 records only**
SELECT  distinct c.Code,c.Name, c._ts FROM c 
Where c.Name = 'SomeName' 
ORDER BY c._ts desc
OFFSET 50 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Have you tried any of these? Did you get back any exceptions?

Comment: No exception, I am getting different result. as you can see above

Comment: Orderby, distinct, and limit does not give rigth result

Comment: Would be great if you can add the expected result, which columns needed to be distinct in the question.

Comment: It was my mistake. in Data explorer it show load more. once I click. I can see more records.